# How to pass the useRef hook value from one component to another?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently learning React and specifically hooks. I am trying to create a canvas where I am using the hook 'useRef'. I get this point that whenever I have to create a reference to my Canvas I can use the 'useRef' hook and by can also use it to point to other canvas properties.
My question is in the code below I have created a component named "UseWBoard" and I want to pass my ctxReference.current value to the "Marker" component.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const UseWBoard = () => {
  const canvasReference = useRef(null);
  const ctxReference = useRef(null);

  let initPaint = false;

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasReference.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = "25";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctxReference.current = ctx;
  }, []);

  function startDraw({ nativeEvent }) {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = nativeEvent;
    ctxReference.current.beginPath();
    ctxReference.current.moveTo(offsetX, offsetY);
    initPaint = true;
  }

  function stopDraw() {
    ctxReference.current.closePath();
    initPaint = false;
  }
  function sketch({ nativeEvent }) {
    if (!initPaint) {
      return;
    }
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = nativeEvent;
    ctxReference.current.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY);
    ctxReference.current.stroke();
  }

  function Marker() {
    ctxReference.current.lineCap = "round";
    ctxReference.current.lineWidth = "1";
    ctxReference.current.strokeStyle = "black";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={Marker}>abc</button>
      <canvas
        ref={canvasReference}
        onMouseDown={startDraw}
        onMouseUp={stopDraw}
        onMouseMove={sketch}
      ></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

const Mark = (ctxReference) => {
  ctxReference.current.lineCap = "round";
  ctxReference.current.lineWidth = "1";
  ctxReference.current.strokeStyle = "black";
};

export { UseWBoard, Mark };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: In your code, Marker is not a component (nor is Mark) -- it's a helper function.  What are you trying to do?